# R Join tables based on timestamp falling within a date range and serial number

Tags: r

I have a study where I have dataloggers positioned throughout my study area that record detections of animals that pass within a specific range. My primary dataframe ("Detections") consists of a column of timestamps for each detection ("TimeStampLocal") - each on a individual row in my dataframe, a column with a serial number that indicates which datalogger this detection was recorded on ("RecSerial") and several other columns with detection related data. This table is large (~ 800k rows).

I need to join this data with a second dataframe ("Receivers") which contains location specific information. There are three important columns for joining in this second table: "Deploy" and "Removal" columns with deployment and removal timestamps and a "RecSerial" column with values that respond to dataframe 1 ("Detections").

Unfortunately my dataloggers were moved around over the course of the study and so table 2 ("Receeivers") has multiple entries for a unique "RecSserial". Of course each receiver is only in one place at one time as indicated by the "Deploy" and "Removal" timestamps. I need to join these two tables by "RecSerial" and "TimeStampLocal" making sure all values are joined with the information associated with the receiver where it was deployed at that time (as denoted by the start and stop time).

I have tried using the tidy verse and also a package that seems like it should work called "fuzzyjoin". However, when fuzzy join completes it makes a ton of the columns I am not using for the joining, but still need in the final dataframe, NA. Below is some code I have run:

```
D1 <- fuzzy_left_join(Detections, Receivers,
                 by = c("RecSerial" = "RecSerial",
                        "TimeStampLocal" = "Deploy",
                        "TimeStampLocal" = "Removal"),
                 match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))
```

Comment: fyi since v1.1.0, dplyr allows inequality joins. I'd expect something like `Detections %>% left_join(Receivers %>% distinct(RecSerial, Deploy, Removal), join_by(RecSerial, TimeStampLocal >= Deploy, TimeStampLocal <= Removal))` should work.

Comment: Is there any way you can demonstrate the issue with some rows of sample or fake data? (ideally as code -- often easiest to use the `dput()` function)

Comment: Thank you Jon - I will try this and update accordingly - with code if necessary!